# Calling stored procedure from java code using hibernate/jdbc with list of values/objects as parameter

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, stored-procedures, jdbc

Is there a way to call a stored procedure created on SQL server via java code using hibernate/jdbc with passing list of values/objects as parameters?
If yes then how can i achieve it?
I know how to call a stored procedure, but i have used stored procedures so far with passing only few parameters and not a complete list of values as i intend to do batch update/insert.
If i do something like the following, would that make sense?

```
getTemplate().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("CALL proc_insert(:list)").setParameterList("list", objList).executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 1):

this may help
Use callableStatement

```
String getDBUSERByUserIdSql = "{call getDBUSERByUserId(?,?,?,?)}";
callableStatement = dbConnection.prepareCall(getDBUSERByUserIdSql);
callableStatement.setInt(1, 10);
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(3, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(4, java.sql.Types.DATE);

// execute getDBUSERByUserId store procedure
callableStatement.executeUpdate();

String userName = callableStatement.getString(2);
String createdBy = callableStatement.getString(3);
Date createdDate = callableStatement.getDate(4);
```

For more Info [click](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-callablestatement-stored-procedure-out-parameter-example/)

Comment: In the above answer, to access the underlying `dbConnection` object from Hibernate session, you could use `getTemplate().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().connection()`

Comment: What i want to do here is update at the max 100 records at a time. for each update i would be inserting a new row in history table.and i am absolutely clueless as to how i should approach this scenario.i dont know how to pass 100 values to a procedure and how i am going to update and insert records from the procedure. can anyone point me in the right direction? at the moment i am updating and inserting one records at a time by looping using hibernate (using dao.update(obj)).